# Concourse CI, get and put a git-resource

Tags: concourse

I'm trying to use a git-resource to get, modify and push a file but it isn't work, can someone help me?

The two resources point to the same git repository and the goal is to add a file in the repository.
I can't understand where I'm wrong, concourse output is green but the repository doesn't have the new file

This is the job:

```
jobs:
- name: myjob
  plan:
  - get: input-repo
  - get: output-repo

  - task: simpletask
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: ubuntu
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
          - -exc
          - |
            cat a_file > output-repo/another_file
      inputs:
      - name: input-repo
      - name: output-repo

  - put: input-repo
    params: { repository: output-repo }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should not need two different resources for this. What you want to do is to `get` (`git clone`) the repo, modify it, `git commit` it and then `put` (`git push`) it.

So you want something like this.

```
jobs:
- name: myjob
  plan:
  - get: repo

  - task: simpletask
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: ubuntu
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
          - -exc
          - |
            cp -r repo changed-repo
            cat a_file > changed-repo/another_file
            git add .
            git commit -m "message"

      inputs:
      - name: repo

  - put: repo
    params: { repository: changed-repo }
```